# post author Id turn into author username in node js for mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman, mongoose-schema

i am trying to have my post's author's name in frontend. so i want to find the post according to it's user Id. but in model schema i used obejct Id of user in post Schema.
Here is my userSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// user schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    salt: String,
bio: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: 'subscriber'
    },
    
    resetPasswordToken: String, 
    resetPasswordExpire: Date,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

here is my postSchema model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    
      content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      comments: [{
        text: String,
        created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        postedBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
      }],
      created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      },
      creator: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
    },
    );
    

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

and here is my router for post lists by a specific user id:

```
exports.postByUser=async(req,res)=>{
  
  try
  {
    const userID=async()=>{
      await User.findById({ _id:req.params.id})
     .then(posts=>{
       res.status(200).json(posts.name)
       
     })
   }  

   await Post.find({creator: req.params.id})
    .then(posts=>{
      res.status(200).json(posts)

    })
   }catch(error){
    res.status(500).send({error: error.message});
  };
}

router.route('/post/mypost/:id').get(requireSignin,postByUser);
```

my target is to get a post list where every post's creator would have the user name. how can i achieve that in nodejs?

Comment: You can use the `$lookup` query to "join" two collections and get the user name.

Comment: You can also store the user name along with the ObjectId within the posts collection. This kind of design is possible as the user's name may not change often and is static. But, when the name changes happen, you may have to update the user name in the user as well as the post collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved this way:

```
exports.postByUser=async(req,res)=>{  
  try
  {
    await Post.find({creator: req.params.id})
    .populate({path:'creator', select:'name -_id'})
    .then(post=>{
      res.status(200).json(post)    
    })

   }catch(error){
    res.status(500).send({error: error.message});
  };
}
```

and it worked